# How to create a pattern matching for below string

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

String - AAHKV2X7AFYLW|2115|R2QLNB6KDC93LF

I am trying to create a pattern that will pull the last part of the string, i.e., R2QLNB6KDC93LF.

In all cases, it starts with |R......... so such a pattern will be useful.

I am looking in Redshift.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I have tagged it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use LIKE, and specify the amount of characters expected, like this:

```sql
WHERE colName LIKE '%_|R_____________'
```

you can test it easily like this:

```sql
SELECT  1
WHERE   'AAHKV2X7AFYLW|2115|R2QLNB6KDC93LF' LIKE '%_|R_____________'
```

(returns 1 because matching)

Comment: I am trying to pull it in a separate column.